# Apache/PHP error: script '[PATH]/products@2x.html' not found or unable to stat

Tags: php, apache

I've never seen this before... on my site, I can search for something and the form submits to "products.html?t=ABC" *(t=search term)*

In the apache logs, I'm seeing the error

```
Apache/PHP error: script '[PATH]/products@2x.html' not found or unable to stat
```

1. products.html is not a "script" - it's an HTML file with embedded PHP - is that just apache being apache?
2. the product search results page loads perfectly fine - the php is executed and there isn't a problem - I'm just asking why I see this in the logs
3. Doesn't seem like the browser is doing it as the Chome and Safari and FF all do it.

**UPDATE 3/22/23** I should be more clear. My search box submits to an intermediate page "search-engine.html" ... that page is 100% PHP and just does some logging/formatting and prepping of the full URL (there are facets and all kinds of things going on). In the end, it does a PHP header redirect...

```
header("Location: [site_url]/products.html?[stuff here]")
```

To clarify, the user never sees search_engine.html - that page doing a header redirect seems to cause apache to look for the products@2x.html file for some reason. The header() line is the last line of the php file.

**UPDATE 3/24/23** This was my DUMB mistake. I thought the browser was doing this @2x nonsense looking for Retina (high res) images... WRONG. This site was built on a bootstrap theme that included **Retina.js** in the includes. THAT JS script caused the problems. Once I saw the access log, it was filled with 1000s of lines of 404 errors as retina.js looked for a @2x file for EVERY IMAGE on EVERY PAGE. Why it looked for a retina version of .html is beyond me - but frankly, I don't have any high-res images. Deleted it. All is fixed. I was going to delete this post but thought it might be useful for someone else.

Comment: If you've got Apache configured to process *.html files as PHP because they might have PHP embedded in them, then I'd argue that _"products.html is not a script"_ is definitively false. That said, do these errors match 1:1 with search form submissions? Or are these hits possibly coming from some external source?

Comment: Maybe grep your source for `@2x`, you might have some errant characters in the URL string for a form's `action` attribute or an AJAX post target.

Comment: @AlexHowansky. Apache processes .html  as php. 100% me submitting the form - 1:1 with me submitting it (site isn't THAT busy)

Comment: @AlexHowansky greped for -@2x- first thing - doesn't exist. I don't "do retina" images so it isn't me. Updating my question...

Comment: Impossible to debug this further without seeing any code. Is the mystery hit a GET or a POST? What's the user agent? Is it an AJAX hit? Is the source IP that of your browser or your server?

Comment: @AlexHowansky Thanks Alex for the help!